# Command not executed npm run build in react

Tags: reactjs, npm

I get an error message when I want to get output in the React project. Please help me.

**and this is my error:**

npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-21T17_21_09_322Z-debug.log

**and this is address in log:**

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~prebuild: myapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: myapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\newpro\mypanel\node_modules.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;f:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\newpro\mypanel
10 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid myapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\newpro\mypanel
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myapp@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: try removing node_modules and package-lock.json.  Then run `npm i` and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file. Then run `npm install`.

This will fix your issue.